# Can't resolve "com.iheart" % "sbt-play-swagger" % "0.5.2-PLAY2.4"

Tags: scala, swagger

According to the doc(https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger), we need to add Swagger sbt plugin dependency to plugins.sbt.

in the project/plugins.sbt i defined the resolver

```
resolvers += "iheart-sbt-plugin-releases" at "https://dl.bintray.com/iheartradio/sbt-plugins"

addSbtPlugin("com.iheart" % "sbt-play-swagger" % "0.5.2-PLAY2.4")
```

However, when run the sbt compile, it throws following errors:

```
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] :: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES ::
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] :: com.iheart#play-swagger_2.10;0.5.2-PLAY2.4: not found
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn] Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn] com.iheart:play-swagger_2.10:0.5.2-PLAY2.4 ((com.iheart.sbtPlaySwagger.SwaggerPlugin) SwaggerPlugin.scala#L28)
```

Anybody can help on this?

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in the docs? https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger#get-started ie. enable and define model package in `build.sbt`?
Its is working ok for me, but I am using Play 2.5. I can see the dependencies in bintray - https://dl.bintray.com/iheartradio/sbt-plugins/com.iheart/sbt-play-swagger/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.5.2-PLAY2.4/

Comment: Thanks Nio.  i have added   "com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.3.12" in the build.sbt already.    If you check the docs this is the first step that we need to do(adding sbtplugin).  Not sure if it is because of scala and play version issue.  I will create a new project and have a try.